# Cannot restart dnscache (DNS Client) service

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

I have cached DNS records which Windows just won't to let go of. I, of course have tried `ipconfig /flushdns` many times which tells me it was successful, but isn't. I am unable to run `net stop dnscache` at all, I get this error:

> The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service.
>
> More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2191.

(There is no more information than that when running the `helpmsg` command.)

I've uninstalled Hyper-V (and rebooted) as I read that there's a known bug that causes conflicts with restarting this service, but it has had no effect.

Edit: I also tried using `psexec` as the Network Service user to restart the service, but that fails, too.

Does anyone know how I can force Windows to *really* clear the DNS cache?

Comment: Did you try to end the dependent processes? : sc qc dnscache                     
-> sc queryex "Prozess" -> taskkill /f /pid

Comment: @Wiffzack the dependencies list `Tdx` and `nsi`; the former not even showing up in the services list so I'm not sure about stopping that one. More importantly, does that actually wipe the store of outdated DNS records?

Comment: facing the same issue